# Porous bounded set

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces

I am working with the following definition of porous set:

**Definition:** A measurable set $E \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is *porous with porosity constant $\delta \in (0,1)$* if every ball $B_{r}(x)$ ($x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$) constains a smaller ball $B_{\delta r}(y)$ such that $B_{\delta r}(y) \subseteq B_{r}(x) \setminus E$.

The problem is the following:

**Problem:** Prove that if $E$ is bounded and for every ball $B=B_{r}(x)$ centered at $x \in E$ there exists a ball $B^{\prime}=B_{\delta r}(y)$ such that $B^{\prime} \subset B \setminus E,$ then $E$ is $c_{n} \delta$ -porous.

Here, $c_{n}$ is a constant that depends on the dimension. I think that (maybe) $c_{n}$ comes from an argument using covering theorems, such as Vitali's lemma or Besicovitch's lemma.

Here is my attempt: Let $B_{\rho}(z)$ be a ball with $z \notin E$. We separate the proof in two cases. First, if $B_{\rho}(z) \cap E=\emptyset$, is easy to see that there exists $y$ such that $B_{\delta \rho}(y) \subseteq B_{\rho}(z) \setminus E=B_{\rho}(z)$. Indeed, take $y=z+e (1-\delta) \rho$, where $e$ is an unitary vector. Then, if $w \in B_{\delta \rho}(y)$, by the triangular inequality
$$|z-w| \leq |z-y|+|w-y|<(1-\delta)\rho + \delta \rho=\rho,$$
so $B_{\delta \rho}(y) \subseteq B_{\rho}(z)=B_{\rho}(z) \setminus E$.

The other case is when we have $B_{\rho}(z) \cap E \neq \emptyset$...

So I need a hint to following this idea, or to take another way to finish the proof. I undestand that I need to find a smaller ball with radious $c_{n} \delta \rho$ which is inside of $B_{\rho}(z) \setminus E$, but I just can not figure out how to use the hypothesis to obtain that.

**Edit (15/04):** It seems like the boundedness conditions is not necessary. This come from remark 1.1 in [this paper](https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1112/jlms/s2-44.1.135) (I can only see page 1, but if someone can see the reference [6] and tell me the paper, I will appreciate it).

Comment: I had to read the problem a couple times to see what it was asking.  The point is that you are assuming that the porosity condition holds only at points $x \in E$, and you want to show that it also holds at points $x \notin E$.

Comment: @NateEldredge yes. In the definition I emphasized that the porosity condition is for $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. The problem now is that I need to try to connect the hypothesis for balls with center at $E$ with ball with arbitrary center. I think that this could de possible taking a cover by open ball with center on $\overline{E}$ and radious $\rho$, and using compactness and some kind of covering lemma (Vitali, Besikovich) one try to gets the relation.